# Questions about calibrate.cph function in rms package

Tags: survival-analysis, cox-regression, calibration, survival, rms

I have made a cph model using survival:coxph (see below)

I am now having some difficulties using the model performance functions in the rms package.

I keep on hitting this error when running the code:

*Error in if (unit == "") unit <- "Day" : argument is of length zero*

Can someone advise me on this?

**calibration**

```
library(polspline)
units(data$time_event) <- "Day"
final.model <- coxph(Surv(data$time_event, data$event) ~ RANDRES + ns(AGE, 3) + aneurysmlocation + ns(LUMENSIZE, 3), data = data)

cal <- calibrate.cph(final.model, cmethod=c('hare', 'KM'), 
          method="boot", u, m=150, pred, B=200, 
          bw=FALSE, rule="aic", type="residual", sls=0.05, aics=0, force=NULL,
          estimates=TRUE,
          pr=FALSE, what="observed-predicted", tol=1e-12, maxdim=5)
```

Comment: Does this occur if you correct the error of extraction of Surv parameters with ‘$’?

Comment: There also possibly a requirement that you have used datadist()